# Execute route change before event function

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I've got a list of menu items and each is an `a` tag. Inside those, I've got notification bubbles insides a `div`. When the notification `div` is clicked, I'd like to first follow the `a` tag (the hash is always to a Meteor route, using Iron Router) before it executes the click event attached to the div. Since reverse-propagation hasn't existed since the netscape days, I thought maybe that click event could store a function as a callback when the route changes? Has anyone tried to do something similar? Couldn't find anything in the Iron Router docs about it. I'm currently mitigating the problem with a few `Session` vars, but would like to clean it up.

Comment: So it should: 1st solve pathTo, then 2nd show bubble notification? How is this bubble notification called?

Comment: FYI, a `div` element inside an `a` element is not valid HTML (block elements are not allowed inside inline elements).

Comment: Eduardo, yep! notification is called via a simple event map `'click .notification'`
Peppe, that's so HTML4 :-P. Technically I know you're right, but at this stage of the HTML spec any tag is just a matter of semantics... We can pretend it's a `div` with its own event map if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what your code is currently doing (or even better, a simplified example), I am guessing a bit at what you are trying to do. Maybe you have something like this:

```
<a href="/yourroute"><div id="bubblething">Click Me!</div></a>
```

With a click event:

```
'click #bubblething': function() {
    // Do the bubble thing.
}
```

But the problem is you'd like to trigger the click event after you route but the click is happening to early. Would it be possible to change it to something more like this:

```
<div id="bubblething">Click Me!</div> //no <a> tag.
```

With the click event handling the actually routing first then moving on:

```
'click #bubblething': function(){
    Router.go('/yourroute'); // First you route
    { ... } // Code to handle the notification bubble.
}
```

You may have to update your styling a bit do to the lack of am `<a>` tag but that should be pretty simple. The routing is handled by the click and then other things happen. You can parameterize this so that instead of calling an id you call a class and inject the route.

Comment: I like it. The only difference is in my app you can click the `a` without clicking the notification, so I'll have to duplicate the `Router.go` for both the outer & inner event maps. Not a dealbreaker, though! I'll come back & vote in a bit after I implement. Thanks!

Comment: Is the div needed? An onclick on the anchor that returns false should prevent the browser from navigating to the href.